# Java Calendar returns same millisecond value for two different dates

Tags: java, calendar

This is my first question, so please be gentle with me! I am having a problem with some pre-existing java code. 
It is pretty simple, you pass it two dates in the format "2013-10-31", it then calculates the ms difference between the two values and then does some more calculations after that. The problem is that every now and again, even though two different dates are passed, they both have the same millisecond value. An example of this is if you pass "2013-10-31" and "2013-11-01", it returns the difference as 0. The ms values both being "1385856000000".

Code is:

```
  public int getTotalStartEndTime( java.sql.Date startdate, java.sql.Date enddate, java.sql.Time starttime, java.sql.Time endtime )
```

{

```
if(startdate != null & enddate != null && starttime !=null && endtime!= null){

     Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
     Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    int styr = Integer.parseInt(startdate.toString().substring(0,startdate.toString().indexOf("-")),10);
    int stmm = Integer.parseInt(startdate.toString().substring(startdate.toString().indexOf("-")+1,startdate.toString().lastIndexOf("-")),10);
    int stdd = Integer.parseInt(startdate.toString().substring(startdate.toString().lastIndexOf("-")+1),10);         
    int enyr = Integer.parseInt(enddate.toString().substring(0,enddate.toString().indexOf("-")),10);
    int enmm = Integer.parseInt(enddate.toString().substring(enddate.toString().indexOf("-")+1,enddate.toString().lastIndexOf("-")),10);
    int endd = Integer.parseInt(enddate.toString().substring(enddate.toString().lastIndexOf("-")+1),10);

    //calendar1.set(styr, stmm, stdd);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, styr);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, stmm);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, stdd);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
    //calendar2.set(enyr, enmm, endd);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.YEAR, enyr);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.MONTH, enmm);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, endd);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

    long milliseconds1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
    long milliseconds2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
    long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I cannot work out what is happening!

Comment: The input data is not clear from your code base. Please try to test the different parts eg. in unit tests to check where exactly it goes wrong.

Comment: Hi, I have tested each line of the code and it all seems to work fine. Debugging the code comes back as: styr = 2013, stmm = 10, stdd= 31, enyr = 2013, enmm = 11, endd = 1

Comment: This is a horrible kludge to work with `Date` values - rather use the `setTime` method on class `Calendar` to set calendars value from a date. And if you absolutely need to parse date strings, use a `DateFormat`

Comment: Yes, I agree. To be honest it wasn't me who wrote the code. If I get the time I will re-write it but it will mean a lot more testing as it is used by a large number of users

Comment: FYI, doing date, time, and calendar work is much easier using the 3rd-party library, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Or in the future with Java 8, the new [JSR 310: Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) which was inspired by Joda-Time. With those libraries you can work with meaningful objects (years, months, days, hours, etc.) rather than doing math with milliseconds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

calendar month is 0-11, in your code, you parsing date from string and month 10 is converted to november, which has not 31 days and set to first december.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense as to why it would only do this on a number of occasions per year. So if I decrement the month value to solve this problem, would it cause any more problems?

Comment: very subtle to note.. +1 for that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

As it has been said, MONTH is 0-11.
Your code didn't throw an exception since the default value of lenient is true.
You should set it to false (unless you explicitly want this behavior) to detect this kind of situation more easily :

```
calendar1.setLenient(false);
calendar2.setLenient(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not actually answering your question, but if all you need is the value of `diff`, there is no need to work with `Calendar` instances, but you can replace your code entirely with:

`long diff = enddate.getTime() - startdate.getTime();`

If you actually need the `Calendar` objects for other operations, there is still no need to parse the string representation of the dates, you can simply set the `Calendar` to the `Date` value with one operation:

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar1.setTimeInMillis(startdate.getTime());
```